# Ubuntu 16.04 connected; can't browse, ping or dig - but can over VPN?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, ping

I have had a strange problem start cropping up: when I'm connected to Wifi (I've tried on multiple different wireless networks, which worked for other devices without a problem), my laptop can't browse at all. Ping and dig turn up nothing but unknown host issues. The problem has persisted across reboots, and seems active even when firewalls are disabled. The only piece of information I can add to this is that my wireless device is now calling itself wls1 - while I can't be 100% that it used to be wlan0, I'm pretty sure it was.

The other curious mystery is that my computer *can* connect to a VPN, and from that VPN, the internet works as expected. I haven't been able to find anyone with a problem like this, so I'm not really sure where to proceed. I'd prefer not to be tied to my VPN for browsing, especially since captive portals would now cripple my device.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://askubuntu.com/a/892739/664380

First (https://askubuntu.com/a/164351/664380)

```
$ sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
```

Then, run (https://askubuntu.com/a/835198/664380)

```
$ ifconfig
```

and see the name of your network adapter. Mine is: enp0s31f6

now run this command

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and you should get something inside....delete everything and paste this (but change the network adapter name where enp0s31f6 is):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

save the document and reboot...