# I can't connect to internet without using my VPN with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: network-manager, internet, dns, vpn

I am new to Linux. I was thinking that I had trouble with the wifi driver until I found out that I could connect to the web when I use a VPN. My Internet was working fine until today. I need to be able to connect to the web without using a VPN.

The messages I get are below:

```
Firefox can’t find the server at www.google.com.
```

On the terminal:

```
$ uname -a  
Linux MisterX 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com

$ dig google.com  
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ ping ping 216.58.208.78
PING 216.58.208.78 (216.58.208.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.208.78: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=230 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.78: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=226 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.78: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=249 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.78: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=224 ms
^C
--- 216.58.208.78 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 224.005/232.736/249.737/10.094 ms

$ dig 216.58.208.78
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> 216.58.208.78
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

I have tried:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
[ ok ] Restarting network-manager (via systemctl): network-manager.service.
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, it works with both:

First (https://askubuntu.com/a/164351/664380)

```
$ sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
```

Then, run (https://askubuntu.com/a/835198/664380)

```
$ ifconfig
```

and see the name of your network adapter. Mine is: enp0s31f6

now run this command

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and you should get something inside....delete everything and paste this (but change the network adapter name where enp0s31f6 is):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

save the document and reboot...

In my case I had only in /etc/network/interfaces the three lines below

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I had to add on top

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
```

and below:

```
# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```