# Network work only on some sites

Tags: networking, internet

i tried to create a ftp server to my home and i went to my router settings and pressed enable on DMZ for port forwarding...
now no site is working except Stackoverflow and AskUbuntu... ( IDK HOW ).
i have tried to reset router and turn off / on but nothing works...
my phone and the other computers detecting the internet but is loading forever.
ping aswell showing me this:

```
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known
```

or when i try stackoverflow or askubuntu with pings its giving me the same error as google ^^ but i can access through the firefox webbrowser.
BTW: I Posted this post from my machine which has the internet problems.

Im using cable, and here is output:
Sorry but im from phone so i needed to type everything:

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp4s0
iface enp4a0 inet dhcp
```

And here is: sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
Product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
Physical id: 0
Bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
Logical Name: enp4s0
Version: 0c
Serial: bc:ee:7b:8d:85:82
Size:  1Gbit/s
Capacity: 1Gbit/s
Width: 64 bits
Clock: 33 MHz
Capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.100.102.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
Resources: irq:35 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe100000-fe100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

Sorry for the mess i tried to take photo but i have issue with that and i couldn't find the  in the phone...

Comment: What if you disable DMZ? Your error message indicates that DNS is not working... can you ping 8.8.8.8? Is your Internet connection DSL, cable, or something else?

Comment: Ping 8.8.8.8 works. And i have tried to reset network settings now i cant even go to thr sites i said on the question...

Comment: You didn't answer all of my questions. Which network settings did you reset?

Comment: This one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/835195/how-do-i-reset-my-network-settings-to-default

Comment: **You still didn't answer my original questions**. Also, please edit your question to show me the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Use copy/paste. Not in the comments, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a typo in your /etc/network/interfaces file:

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change this:

```
iface enp4a0 inet dhcp
```

To this:

```
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
```

Then reboot your computer.

- And also, replace your r8169 driver:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms

reboot
```

- Lastly, make sure that your MTU setting in your `Wired Connection` network profile is set for 1500 or automatic. Same thing in your router.

Comment: did what you said and sudo apt get update is stuck at 0 percent and saying: [connecting to archive.ubuntu.com] same with all the other repositorys after that its giving me error: could not resolve 'repos name'..

Comment: You still have a DNS problem. You never did say what happens if you disable DMZ in your router. Also, do you have DNS servers defined in your `Wired Connection` network profile? If not, enter some and retry.

Comment: DMZ is disable by default im only enable it for ping 'external ip address' and bring it back for disable. Mind to explain me how to see dns servers? I cant find it... btw is there anyway i can format the router from terminal? because i had this problem once and i called the company and they formated it. Btw network settings saying Wired - unmanaged - 1000 mb/s. If its mean anything...

Comment: To reset the router, log into the router, find the `Admin` or `Manage` tab, and choose `Reset to factory`... however, note, that you'll loose any custom settings that you've made. Before doing that, you might try plugging the ethernet cable from your computer directly into your cable modem, reboot both, and see if it works.

Comment: Yea but i cant get to router settings... I typing in the firefox thr ipv4 and its loading forever until error like other sites.

Comment: Try the recable suggestion. Power cycle the modem and reboot the computer, then retry the Internet.

Comment: i called the company of the internet and they reset to factory . thanks for help anyway!